# Flutter/FirebaseStorage ref.getDownloadURL() gives : No App Check token for request

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm working with the following code and am getting this `Network Task` and `FirebaseStorage` error:

```
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('user_image')
        .child('${userCredential.user?.uid}.jpg');
ref.putFile(image);
final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();

await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userCredential.user!.uid)
        .set({'username': username, 'email': email, 'image_url': url});
```

Error As follows:

```
W/NetworkRequest(14051): No App Check token for request.
I/flutter (14051): [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
```

Even though the file is in fact put into storage, and I have not enabled App Check on the project. The error is causing subsequent code where I set the URL to the Firestore to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual error is:

> [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.

This is because you call `putFile` **before** the file has completed uploading, so there is no file at the path yet. To wait for the file to be available, use `await` on the `putFile` call too:

```
await ref.putFile(image);
```